# SVG Circle color with gradient

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js, svg, radial-gradients

I want to use svg to draw circle color like image below. I tried many ways but not have perfect result. 
Anybody have solution. Should I use javascript library like d3js
Thank you

[Circle color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCvzN.png)

Comment: Where is your code?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```css
svg {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<svg width="400" height="400">
  <defs>
    <filter id="blur">
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="7"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <g filter="url(#blur)">
    <circle cx="200" cy="210" r="170" fill="#f00"/>
    <circle cx="180" cy="180" r="150" fill="#00f"/>
    <circle cx="170" cy="210" r="140" fill="#f0f"/>
    <circle cx="240" cy="220" r="130" fill="#00f"/>
    <circle cx="240" cy="180" r="130" fill="#0ff"/>
    <circle cx="240" cy="240" r="120" fill="#ff0"/>

    <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="150" fill="#fff"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```